# How to create dictionary of event handlers

Tags: c#, events

> Please note I do NOT think this is a complete duplicate. There are similar
>   questions but none have managed to approach the issue in this way.

I have multiple threads that wait for a "Cancel" event. But the Cancel event contains a key(algoIdent) that allows me to direct a callback to a specific thread.

I want to use a dictionary with key of algoIdent and value of my CallBack delegate.

However, I do not know how to create a new instance of an event ( I don't mean adding a listener). The commented-out code shows how I do it for a single listener, but I don't know what to put in the Value part of the dictionary.Add():

```
public delegate void delProcessCancel(string algoIdent,  string callBackMessage);
//public event delProcessCancel ProcessCancelListeners;
public Dictionary<string, delProcessCancel > ProcessCancelListenerDict = new Dictionary<string, delProcessCancel>();

        public void AddProcessCancelListener(string algoIdent, delProcessCancel _delProcessCancel)
        {
            if (!ProcessCancelListenerDict.ContainsKey(algoIdent))
            {                    
                ProcessCancelListenerDict.Add(algoIdent, event _delProcessCancel );
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: `ProcessCancelListenerDict.Add(algoIdent, _delProcessCancel );` will compile but I'm really not sure what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: True but the value will be a delegate not an event. So I can't fire it

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: You mean like this? `ProcessCancelListenerDict["ident"](algoIdent, callBackMessage)`?

Comment: @DavidG Almost. That's just calling the delegate, I want it to work exactly like when an event is fired. I think your version would have issues with thread crossing

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question becuase I figured you could create a new event in a new class. So, I created a wrpper.

Does anybody feel that there is an issue in doing it this way?

```
  public class ProcessCancelEventWrapper
    {
        public event delProcessCancel ProcessCancelListeners;

        public ProcessCancelEventWrapper(delProcessCancel _delProcessCancel)
        {
            ProcessCancelListeners += _delProcessCancel;
        }

        public void Raise(string algoIdent, string callBackMessage)
        {
            ProcessCancelListeners(algoIdent, callBackMessage);
        }
    }

    public delegate void delProcessCancel(string algoIdent,  string callBackMessage);

    public Dictionary<string, ProcessCancelEventWrapper> ProcessCancelListenerDict = new Dictionary<string, ProcessCancelEventWrapper>();


    public enum ListenerOption { Add, Delete, };
    public void ManageProcessCancelListener(string algoIdent, delProcessCancel _delProcessCancel, ListenerOption listenerOption)
    {
        if (listenerOption==ListenerOption.Add)
        {
            if (!ProcessCancelListenerDict.ContainsKey(algoIdent))
            {
                ProcessCancelListenerDict.Add(algoIdent, new ProcessCancelEventWrapper(_delProcessCancel));
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessCancelListenerDict[algoIdent].ProcessCancelListeners += _delProcessCancel;
            }                
        }
        else if (listenerOption == ListenerOption.Delete)
        {
            if (!ProcessCancelListenerDict.ContainsKey(algoIdent))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessCancelListenerDict[algoIdent].ProcessCancelListeners -= _delProcessCancel;
            }
        }

    }

    public void RaiseProcessCancelListener(string algoIdent, string callBackMessage)
    {
        if (!ProcessCancelListenerDict.ContainsKey(algoIdent))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessCancelListenerDict[algoIdent].Raise(algoIdent, callBackMessage);
        }
    }
```